# Karma WARN [web-server] error for endpoint

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

When I run my karma tests, I keep getting the following WARN errors.

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: /api/my_example_endpoint
WARN [web-server]: 404: /api/my_example_endpoint
WARN [web-server]: 404: /api/my_example_endpoint
WARN [web-server]: 404: /api/my_example_endpoint
```

This `my_example_endpoint` is being called from a UI-router `resolve` for all views. Something like...

```
  .state('global', {
      abstract: true,
      resolve: {
        exampleResolve: function(MyExampleService) {
          // this calls the '/api/my_example_endpoint' endpoint
          return MyExampleService.getGlobalData();
        }
      },
      //....
    })
```

And `MyExampeService.getGlobalData()` makes an $http call..

```
 angular.module('example')
    .factory('MyExampleService', ['$resource',
      function($resource) {
        var service, getGlobalData;

        service = $resource('/api/my_example_endpoint', {}, {
          get: {
            method: 'GET'
          },
        });

        /**
         * Returns a promise
         */
        getGlobalData = function() {
          return service.get().$promise;
        };

        return {
          getGlobalData: getGlobalData
        };

      }
    ]);
```

In my `karma.conf.js` file, the files are in this order.

```
    // lib files
    'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
    'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
    'public/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
    'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
    'public/lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
    'public/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
    'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
    'public/lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js',
    'public/lib/underscore/underscore.js',
     // my application files
    'public/config.js',
    'public/application.js',
    'public/dist/js/templates.js',
    'public/modules/*/*.js',
    'public/modules/*/directives/*/*.js',
    'public/modules/*/*[!tests]*/*.js',
    'public/modules/*/*[!mocks]*/*.js',
     // test files
    'public/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'public/modules/*/**/*.mocks.js',
    'public/modules/*/**/*.test.js'
```

**How can I fix this `WARN` error?**

Comment: Are you using [angular-mocks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock) library? It intercepts all ajax request made from `$http`, and you can override it

Comment: Yea, I'm using the angular-mocks library. How can I suppress that `WARN` error?

Comment: Is your `MyExampleService.getGlobalData()` call using `$http` to perform a request to api?

Comment: It uses `$resource`..it's basically `$resource('/api/my_example_endpoint', {}, { get: {  method: 'GET' }, })`

Comment: That's weird. Angular intercepts that requests by default. Check the order of including your test files and ensure that `angular-mocks` goes before your code

Comment: I updated my post with the order from my `karma.conf.js` file. Is it because `angular-mocks` should be before the application files?

Comment: I'm using a node proxy for `/api/my_example_endpoint`. So, technically that endpoint points to `http://localhost:8000/v1/my_example_endpoint`. So if I add a `proxies` to the `karma.conf.js` it seems to suppress the error...But not entirely sure if thats the right thing to do...